# Append input to next row of table

Tags: jquery, append

How can i add an input to the next row in a table, and have it be part of the form that eventually gets submitted? in this case, a row after the address row.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ops21L5c/)

```
$(function(){
       $('#addRow').click(function(){
           $("<tr><td><input type='text' value='' /></td></tr>")
           .attr("id", "city")
           .attr("name", "city")
           .appendTo("#test");
       });
      $('#sub').click(function(){
         var data = $('#test').serialize();
         alert(data);
      });
});


<form id='test' name='test' method='POST' action='#'>
<table align='center'>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='button' id='addRow' value='Add'>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' id='name' name='name'>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' id='address' name='address'>
  </td>
</tr>
<tR>
  <td>
    <input type='button' id='sub'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here, you're appending it to the form.  That's why the textbox is being thrown at the bottom.

If you want to insert it under the last row, what you want to do is `.appendTo` the last tr in your table.  I would try doing something like:

```
.appendTo("tr:last");
```

My assumption is that you want to add another row for a textbox under all the other text boxes.  In that case, I would recommend using the `.insertBefore` command.  That way the box goes before the submit button at the bottom.  Oh, and you'll also probably want to add a label for that textbox (another `td` tag in your JQuery).

```
.insertBefore("tr:last");
```

See if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/HillChris1234/5s9xr638/#&togetherjs=jbqIQewv7L) helps!

Comment: You are encouraging OP to use same id for multiple elements.

Comment: I didn't encourage him to do anything of the sort.  I answered his question.

Comment: Hey, OP... don't use the same id for multiple elements!  Is that better?

Comment: So even it is wrong, you won't correct that in your answer. I mean in your fiddle. You will stay adamant like this. huh?

Comment: Yeah.  If you have a problem with it you can tell him on your own.  I don't work for you.  In your answer, you didn't even explain what's wrong with his code... you just did his homework and said "Here!  Try this!"  How is that helpful?  You didn't even explain to him about the common ids.

Comment: Okay there, Ramadama Dingdong.